# FileNet Content Engine query comparing numbers defined as string

Tags: casting, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-ce-sql

So I have a FileNet search query like this

```
SELECT * from MyPurchase_Docs
WHERE Purchase_Amount > 100.50
```

Very simple query but my problem is that Purchase_Amount is defined as string
so I get results where 
Purchase_Amount is 2.5, 30.25 etc (because it is comparing strings)

I tried CAST function but it does not work with FileNet.
I do not have access to change Field type in Filenet so I am stuck here.
Please let me know if there is a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, data type conversion is not supported.

```
<predicate> ::= <comparison_predicate>
                 | <null_test>
                 | <in_test>
                 | <existence_test>
                 | <isclass_test>
                 | <isOfclass_test>
                 | <content_test>
                 | <satisfies_test>
                 | <intersects_test>
```

```
<comparison_predicate> ::= <scalar_exp> <comparison_op> <scalar_exp>
```

```
<scalar_exp> ::= <literal>
                 | <property_exp>
                 | ( '(' <scalar_exp> ')' )
                 | ( <scalar_exp> <arith_op> <scalar_exp> )
                 | <property_spec> [<arith_op> <timespan_exp>]
                 | <now> [<arith_op> <timespan_exp>]
```

[SQL Statement Grammar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm#query_sql_syntax_rel_queries__sql_statement_grammar)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was hoping there is a way around this but I guess not.